# Python Pandas read excel sheet different range with table headers

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tabs

I am working to read tables in the excel sheet, and want to use the keywords like 'TAB_1', 'TAB_2' to get the values of each table named as 'TAB_1' and 'TAB_2'. Is there a quick syntax in pandas to work on it?

1. what the excel sheet like:
   [image]

2. what I expect to get using the keyword from ['TAB_1', 'TAB_2] 
   df_tab_1 = 
   test_a   test_b 
   1        2 
   3        4 
   df_tab_2 = 
   test_c   test_d 
   5        6 
   7        8  
   as two pandas dataframes

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that with Pandas. As workaround, you can name your [Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e#__toc384648761) in Excel then use `openpyxl` to load them:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

data1 = []
for row in ws[ws.tables['TAB_1'].ref]:
    data1.append([cell.value for cell in row])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1[1:], columns=data1[0])

# Same for df2
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   test_a  test_b
0       1       2
1       3       4

>>> df2
   test_c  test_d
0       5       6
1       7       8
```